# How to use dynamic content in relative URL in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, parameters, azure-data-factory

I have a REST data source where I need pass in multiple parameters to build out a dataset in Azure Data Factory V2.

I have about 500 parameters that I need to pass in so don’t want to pass these individually. I can manually put these in a list (I don’t have to link to another data source to source these). The parameters would be something like [a123, d345, e678]

I'm working in the UI. I cannot figure out how to pass these into the relative URL (where it says Parameter) to then form the dataset. I could do this in Power BI using functions and parameters but can't figure it out in Azure Data Factory as I'm completely new to it. I'm using the Copy Data functionality in ADF to do this.

The sink would be a json file in an Azure blob that I can then access via Power BI. I'm fine with this part.

[Relative URL with Parameter requirement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlJIc.png)

[How to add dynamic content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ps63Z.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that your requirement can't be implemented.As you know,[ADF REST dataset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest) is used to retrieving data from a REST endpoint by using the GET or POST methods with Http request. No way to configure a list of parameters in the `relativeUrl` property which ADF would loop it automaticlly for you.

Two ways to retrieve your goal:

1.Loop your parameter array ,pass single item into `relativeUrl` to execute copy activity individually.Using this way,you could use [foreach activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-for-each-activity) in the ADF.

2.Write a overall api to accept list paramter from the `requestBody`,execute your business in the api inside with loop.